# How to show data from the $scope in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to bring data from my angular controller to my HTML view.

This is the data that I've passed in the $scope.

[image: My $scope variables]

I know how to show objects using ng-repeat.

But how can I show the data that is in the `projectsLength` and `tasksLength`?

I've tried this with no success: `<h1 ng-model="usersLength"></h1>`

Can someone help? ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
<h1>{{usersLength}}</h1>
```

refer [this documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

Answer (score 0):

The term is called an Angular Expression and it would look something like this:

```
{{projectsLength}}
```

Here's a link to Expressions in the Angular docs: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

And here's a great ebook covering the Angular basics.

Scroll down to find the Angular ebook on the list. (You will have to register with your name and phone number, but they have never "harassed" me and their ebooks are excellent!)

https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/ebooks/